# export values from dynamoDB getItem

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get data outside  of the getItem function off the dynamoDB, but I'm getting this error and I don't know why.

```
Error ValidationException: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes
```

Here is my code

```
const aws = require("aws-sdk"),
  docClient = new aws.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" }),
  ddb = new aws.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" }),
  tableName = "usersDB",

 exports.apiKey = async (req, res, context) => {
  var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: {
      "username": { "S": req.body.username },
    },
    ProjectionExpression: "apiKey"
  };

  chaveAPI = await ddb.getItem(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", data.Item);
    }
  });
};
```

EDIT1: Fixed the validation error but still cannot get data from dyname. Here it is fixed

```
exports.apiKey = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("comecei")

    var params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Key: {
          'username': {S: req.user.username}
        },
        ProjectionExpression: 'apiKey'
      };
      
      // Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
      dataFromDynamo = await ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success", data.Item);
          return data.Item
        }
      });

console.log(dataFromDynamo)

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I notice with your code sample:

1. You are mixing callbacks with async/await.
2. You aren't declaring the `dataFromDynamo` variable.

Instead of this

```
     // Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
     dataFromDynamo = await ddb.getItem(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success", data.Item);
          return data.Item
        }
      });
```

Do this

```
try {
    // Call DynamoDB to read the item from the table
    const dataFromDynamo = await ddb.getItem(params).promise()
    console.log("Success", data.Item);
    return data.Item
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new to async. After some tutorials that I found I got it working like you posted.

Comment: Great!  If my answer helped,  consider accepting it as the answer so that it may help others that are experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Sorry. Iḿ new on Stack. Still learning the ropes of it